# How to send array of registeration ids to gcm from android using php

Tags: php, android, arrays, google-cloud-messaging, sinch

I'm trying to send array of registeration ids to the gcm using php but it doesn't work, I'm using sinch and this is my code :

```
class sendPushNotifications extends AutoAsyncTask {

    List<PushPair> pushPairs;

    String message;

    String senderId;

    public sendPushNotifications(Context context, String message, String senderId, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        super(context, false);

        this.message = message;
        this.pushPairs = pushPairs;
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean connectedToInternet = connManager.getNetworkInfo( ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()
                || connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
        if (connectedToInternet) 
        {   
            String regId;
            String[] arrayList = new String[]();

            for(PushPair p: pushPairs)
            {
                regId = new String(p.getPushData());
                arrayList.add(regId);
            }

            UserFunctions.sendPushNotifications(senderId, message, arrayList);

            asyncTask = null;
            return 0;
        }
```

I know that the above code is wrong that's why I'm asking.

(p) is list of pushpairs which contain GCM registeration ids which I can get using the function `p.getPushData()`, what I want to do is to fill an array of strings with each registeration id and send it to my server and then send it to GCM, the code of `UserFunctions.sendPushNotifications(senderId, message, arrayList);` is :

```
public static JSONObject sendPushNotifications(String senderId, String message, String[] gcm_regId) 
    {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senderId", senderId));

        for (int i = 0; i < gcm_regId.length; i++)
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gcm_regId", gcm_regId[i]));

        JSONObject json = JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(hostURL+"gcm.php", params);
        return json;
    }
```

and my PHP code is :

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$gcm_regId = $_POST['gcm_regId'];
$senderId= $_POST['senderId'];

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => array($gcm_regId),
        'data'              => array( 'message' => $message ),
        'senderId'          => $senderId,
);

$headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . '*********************',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

echo json_encode( $result );
```

I can send the notification to the first device that the user signed in using

```
pusPairs.get(0).getPushData();
```

but I want to send the notification to all the devices that the user is signed in to his account with it so some help please.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you trying to send the push notification to multiple devices, but it's only sending to the first registration_id in the array?

Comment: @mravca I know how to send it to one device, but I don't know how to send an array containing all the registeration ids in the pushpairs list from android to php and I also don't know how to send it from php to gcm

Comment: From one Android device, how many registration IDs were you expecting to send to the server? It's usually only one registration ID per app. Can you print out the JSON that you receive from the Android device?

Comment: @koh I'm trying to get all the registeration ids of the user on the other side as pushpairs is a list of registered devices of that user, I get the registeration id of the first device that the user logged in using pushpairs.get (0).getPushData (), but that's not what I want, what I want is getting all the registeration ids of the user if he is using more than a device.

Comment: Yes, each app instance will only have one registration ID. What you can do is, send each registration ID separately, from each device. To verify that they are from a particular user, you can include a payload in each message sent (like a username). Let your PHP server sort all these registration IDs on a per-user basis.

Comment: @koh so what are you suggesting to change in my code?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?